# Thoughts on storing modified views, list designer workflows, list template in a source code repository like TFS

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

Is anyone adding their sharepoint views or list designer workflows into a source repository like TFS? Currently we're required by our audit team to store all of our souce code into a code repository like TFS. This includes not just source code, but anykind of author artifact. I was wondering if anyone is using TFS to store views, list designer workflows or any kind of author artifacts and storing them into TFS. My thought for most of author artifacts, SharePoint enables versions which allows me to retrieve a previous version of a view or a workflow from the content database, so I'm in favor for most author artifacts in SharePoint use the content database as our "Source Code" respository.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brandon,

AFAIK you cannot use TFS for version control for SharePoint views, pages, designer workflows and so on!

Because most of them are not code or do not have files to look for, like Unghosted Pages, views and are generated on run-time, saving all the information in databases!

Exactly as you already said, you can use versions and version approvals for maintaining history/version control... Also as for disaster recovery you can take regular Site Collection backups to be on the safe side! Run jobs to take automatic backups for you, and place them on a safe location [Central Admin]

Wait for the other answers, maybe someone can share more thoughts!